# How do I highlight only employees who work in the same department as their managers?

Tags: sql

So far, I've got the following:

```
SELECT Emp.Empno as "Emp#", Emp.Ename as "Employee", Emp.Deptno as "Department", Emp.Mgr as "Mgr#", M.Ename as "Manager",
FROM Emp
LEFT OUTER JOIN Emp M ON Emp.Mgr = M.Empno;
```

Result:

```
      Emp# Employee       DEPTNO       Mgr# Manager
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7902 FORD               20       7566 JONES
      7788 SCOTT              20       7566 JONES
      7900 JAMES              30       7698 BLAKE
      7844 TURNER             30       7698 BLAKE
      7654 MARTIN             30       7698 BLAKE
      7521 WARD               30       7698 BLAKE
      7499 ALLEN              30       7698 BLAKE
      7934 MILLER             10       7782 CLARK
      7876 ADAMS              20       7788 SCOTT
      7782 CLARK              10       7839 KING
      7698 BLAKE              30       7839 KING
      7566 JONES              20       7839 KING
      7369 SMITH              20       7902 FORD
      7839 KING               10
```

However, I also need to know how to REMOVE the rows where the Employee's DEPTNO DOES NOT match with the DEPTNO of their respective managers (if any) from my results.

I'm truly bushed and have been stuck on it for hours.

Comment: If the employee has no manager, should the employee be included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a where clause to your sql that only selects if the manager and employees deptno are the same

```
SELECT E.Empno as "Emp#", E.Ename as "Employee", E.Deptno as "Department", E.Mgr as "Mgr#", M.Ename as "Manager"
FROM Emp E
LEFT OUTER JOIN Emp M ON E.Mgr = M.Empno
WHERE E.Deptno = M.Deptno;
```

Comment: Wow, it worked... Thanks a bunch! I wish I could give you a useful point.